# Windows 7: Some time my mouse got "virtually" unplugged and plugged again in some seconds

Tags: windows, drivers, virtual-machine, mouse

So guys,

sometime when i am browsing or doing other stuff it's like windows unplugs my usb-logitech-mouse. it than get riconnected again in few seconds.

I tihnk this is happening after I had to install virtual machines (like: virtualbox and vmware)

I already disinstalled them but this issue is still here.

When this happens even the lights on my mouse are off same behaviour as like somone unplagged it.

What could i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that "lights on my mouse are off" during the virtual unplugging. The problem could be in the USB port (h/w) itself. Otherwise at least the "power" should be there.

Did you try another USB port?

Did you try another device (another mouse, keyboard) in the same port and face a similar disconnection?

In that case you would have to replace your port, I think.

Comment: good idea.. i will try my mouse on other usb port

Comment: Ok i tried, on other ports still windows 7 is virutally unplugging it